# How to get rid of DeprecationWarning?

Tags: python, pygame

I keep get this 'warning':

```
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  
  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, 
  and may be removed in a future version of Python.
screen.blit(enemyImg[u], (x, y))
```

This is where I suspect the error comes from:

```
def isCollision(eX, eY, bX, bY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(int(eX) - int(bX), 2) + math.pow(int(eY) - int(bY), 2))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You don't need to suspect anything, exact line is printed in error message.

Comment: The code snippet does not contain the line which causes the warning. Anyway, use `screen.blit(enemyImg[u], (round(x), round(y)))`

Comment: Off-topic: You can replace last 4 lines of `isCollision()` function with `return distance < 27`.